# Mocking a function within a Python Flask Blueprint

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, mocking, patch

I have a Python Flask Blueprint called api, and within it, it has a file called utils that has a function I am trying to Mock. The path to that utils file is `app/api/utils.py`, and the function I'm trying to mock is `is_file_writeable()`.

I am running a test for a route in the Blueprint located at `app/api/configs.py`. Within `configs.py`, I import the function as so:

```
from app.api.utils import is_file_writeable
```

I have tried the following patch decorators:

```
@patch('app.api.configs.is_file_writeable', return_value=False)
```

and

```
@patch('app.api.utils.is_file_writeable', return_value=False)
```

Both return the following errors respectively:

> AttributeError: 'Blueprint' object has no attribute 'configs'

and

> AttributeError: 'Blueprint' object has no attribute 'utils'

Any ideas as to why I am getting an import error?

Comment: What you need is just `@patch('app.api.configs.is_file_writeable', return_value=False)` but from your logs seams that `app.api` is a `Blueprint` object instead a python module. Unfortunately I don't use flask and I cannot help you. You can put something like `print(app.api)` at the top of your test module and take a look if it is a module or not.

Comment: How about providing a full stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

When I ran into this problem it was because `api` was a blueprint. Instead of looking for the `configs.py` under the folder `api` the mocker was looking for something called `utils` in the blueprint `api`.

To get around this I imported the py file and patched the object directly:

```py
from app.api import utils

@patch.object(utils, 'is_file_writeable', lambda x: False)
```